# Set Up CronJob In CPanel Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

i set up a cronjob in cpanel, i'm using laravel 4.2. i also set to send the cronjob to my email and below yellow part is the error i received in email.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>
> There are no commands defined in the "user" namespace.

//laravel command.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class CronDelFilesCommand extends Command {

/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'user:active';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description.';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    echo "aaa";
}

/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return array(

    );
}

/**
 * Get the console command options.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
    );
}

}
```

//command in cpanel

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/project/public_html/artisan user:active > /home/project/public_html/log.txt
```

what's wrong? what's the error mean?

**UPDATED**

thanks to @KristianHareland i use wget. :)

Comment: try use `wget http://www.website.tld/path/to/file` ive had some trouble with cPanel cron jobs as well and figured this was the best workaround.

Comment: @KristianHareland is it not using laravel command anymore?

Comment: @KristianHareland thanks!

Comment: No problem, have a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add this command to artisan `app/start/artisan.php`.

You shoud wright:

```
Artisan::add(new CronDelFilesCommand());
```

And don't forget about `composer dump-autoload`
More info you can find [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#registering-commands).

Comment: i did add new command in artisan.php . what is the composer dump-autoload?

Comment: It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.

Comment: Also I want to recommnend you very nice [lib for Laravel Cron jobs](https://github.com/indatus/dispatcher).

Comment: One important thing. Try to remove array of options.